# Multi-class classification where classes have a ranking

Tags: classification, svm, multi-class

I am trying to come up with a Machine Learning based solution for a situation that involves automatically classifying a number of people into 4 classes - Class 1, Class 2 , Class 3 and Class 4. The classes have a rank associated with them. For example, Class 1 is ranked higher than Class 2 and Class 2 is ranked higher than Class 3 and so on. There are about 25 or so features associated with each person.

Initially, I thought this problem as a Multi-class classification problem. I intend to use SVM or Gradient Boosted Decision Tree using Scikit Learn for Multi-class. I can even use Deep Learning. Perhaps I can try transforming this problem into binary classification, using One-vs-One or One-vs-All classification.

But what I am unsure about is, do all these Multi-class algorithms consider rankings in classes? In other words, for "traditional classification" (for the lack of better word) such as spam vs not-spam classification, there is no order to classes. Spam is not "better" or "ranked higher" than not-spam?

Can you kindly share your thoughts on how best to approach this?

Comment: What are your training data look like? Maybe you can use a series of models: class 1 vs the rest; class 2 vs the rest; class 3 vs the rest. This is like the ordinal logistic regression.